# Replacing a html content with found content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am trying to replace a founded content in HTML body as shown bellow code.

```
var fontReplacer = $("body").html().replace(/\{fontsize:(.*?)\}(.*?(({fontsize\})|$)/g,'<span style="font-size:$1px">$2</span>');
  $("body").html(fontReplacer);
```

But after executing this code, remain functions are not working. Is it write code to replace a content like `{fontsize:12}12px text here{font}` with **12px text here** (in 12px size)
Please help me where i have done mistake

Comment: `bellow all functions are not working.` means what?

Comment: It looks like you are missing quotes around your regex

Comment: @NickWilde — Putting quotes around it would make it a string. It isn't a string, it is a regex.

Comment: look at the errors that get thrown in console

Answer (score 0):

what founded thing you are searching in html, which section.

```
var sel = $('body').find('div'); //mention what which element you are searching for
var sel = $('body').find('span');

for(i = 0; i< sel.length; i++)
 $(sel).css('font-size','1px');
```

similarly for span

Comment: No praveen, I want to add size dynamically, as i got {fontsize:20}text{fontsize}